# Selenium python navigation

Tags: python, selenium, pagination

I want to go to the next page inside a product category on Aliexpress website. But an error appears. How to fix it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://aliexpress.ru/category/202003912/blouses-shirts.html?page=2')
    el = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "SearchPagination_SearchPagination__particularPageInput__16999")
    el.send_keys("5")
    time.sleep(5)
    el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="OK"]')
    el.click()
main()
```

Result:

```
...\temp.py", line 12, in main
    el.click()
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking into aliexpress page, and looking up the xpath on the page, it seems to find two different elements, using the full xpath or another method for it might work, however you can just try using the find elements method which returns a list then interact with the second element.

```py
el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="OK"]')[1]
```